# Imprimir una lista en python introduciendo un salto cada 4 elementos

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, imprimir

Quiero imprimir una lista en python de manera que cada cuarto elemento de la lista se inserte un salto de línea. Lo he intentado pero lo que mas me aproximo es lo siguiente, supongo que debe haber una forma mas elegante de conseguirlo. No?

```
valores=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
for i in range(1,17):
    print(valores [i-1])
    if (i) % 4 == 0:
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción:

```
for i in range(len(valores)):
    print(valores[i], end = ' ' if (i+1)%4 else '\n')
```

Por cada iteración se imprime el `valor`, y el salto de línea que tiene el `print` por default es reemplazado por: un `espacio` si `i+1` no es múltiplo de `4`. De lo contrario agrega un `salto`.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
valores=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
for i in range(0,len(valores),4):
    print('\n'.join( [str(i) for i in valores[i:i+4]]),"\n")
```

explicacion:

1. range acepta 3 parametros

- inicio
- maximo
- pasos o step

2. el metodo **len()** optiene la longitud del arreglo
3. el metodo **join()** pasa un arreglo a string uniendo sus elementos
4. el for interno es llamada sintaxis corta y lo que hacemos es pasar cada elemento del arreglo a string ya que join no acepta int
5. la notacion **valores[i:i+4]** es para hacer un slice
   acepta 3 parametros igual que range para tomar elementos del arreglo
6. pasamos un segundo elemento al print que seria el salto de linea